# What is the difference between an unbounded solution and infinite optimal solutions?

Tags: computer-science, linear-programming

I am currently studying Linear Programming, and one of the few things that I haven't found a *solution* for (pun obviously intended) is the difference between a solution being either *unbounded* or having *infinite optimal solutions*.

My thinking is, if something is unbounded, is that not the same as it being infinite? I must not have a proper understanding of both, as I cannot see why my thinking would correct.

If possible, could someone illustrate the differences with a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unbounded Solution** refers to *one* solution being unbounded, in the sense that the $y = x$ is unbounded.

**Infinite Optimal Solutions** refers to an infinite *family* of functions that are all optimal solutions, in the sense that $x = \pi + 2n\pi$ is an infinity family of solutions to the problem $\min\cos(x)$.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. The only thing I am struggling with then is what *unbounded* actually. Could you kindly elaborate on your point?

Comment: In fact, I may understand it, but without a graph I won't be able to fully show, but I'll try: if you have two constraints and the solution is in between the two lines, that would be considered to have *infinitely many solutions*; whereas if you had one constraint that was *greater than* and $z$ is to be *maximised*, the optimal solution would be anywhere above that line, i.e. *unbounded*. Correct?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20function%20f,is%20said%20to%20be%20unbounded.) clarify what unbounded/bounded functions are?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Thanks for the help :)